# How to copy data to clipboard when user selects "Copy" from ContextMenu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How would you copy the contents of a datagrid cell to the clipboard when the user selects copy from the context menu on a paticular cell?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.MouseClick += dataGridView1_MouseClick;
}

void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));

        int currentMouseOuverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your post says you're using a ContextMenu. Can't you just set a Click event for the ContextMenuItem and get the selected row from then add it to the Clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what I'd do is this:

```
var hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
if (hitTestInfo.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) { return; }

var mi = new MenuItem("Copy")
mi.Tag = hitTestInfo;
mi.Click += (s, e) =>
{
    var hti = ((MenuItem)s).Tag as HitTestInfo;
    var val = dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Cells[hti.ColumnIndex].Value;

    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, val);
}

m.MenuItems.Add(mi);
```

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, right in place of the code you have now. I just modified the code you provided.

Comment: Within `void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` or `public Form1()`

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, I pulled that `HitTest` code right out of the `MouseClick` event handler. Just merge my code in. You'd of course still need the code to create the context menu and show it.

Comment: Also, it will be correct to check for `hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell` before creating menu.

Comment: `DataFormats.UnicodeText` if you're looking for UTF-8 in the clipboard... otherwise it'll use default Windows encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your MouseClick-Method like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        using (ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu())
        {
            MenuItem mItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
            m.MenuItems.Add(mItem);

            DataGridView.HitTestInfo information = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            try
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[information.RowIndex].Cells[information.ColumnIndex];
                m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                mItem.Click += mItem_Click;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that you create a method which is called when the mItem.Click-Event is raised:

```
void mItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a Click event handler to your menu item? Then all you need to do in that event is the following:

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count < 1)
        return;

    var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells["CellName"].Value;
    if (cell != null)
        Clipboard.SetText(cell.ToString());
}
```

Just added a quick edit to make sure there's actually a value in the cell before you go and overwrite whatever's on the clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx) class, in this particular case you want the [SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043.aspx) method.
Note: the msdn says that Clipboard is in System.Windows however on my machine it is in System.Windows.Forms.